# What are K neighbor global scale and range global scale?

Tags: closest-point

I am asking these terms as used in the following link. I understand k-neighbor but not k neighbor global scale.
When I used CGAL it for the 10 points 0 to 9 on x-axis(That is (0,0,0),(1,0,0),....(9,0,0)), it reported, Global K scale = 6;
Global range scale was 3.
But I don't understand why.
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/index.html#Point_set_processing_3Example_scale_estimation_global